# How to set different columns for different devices in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am designing a web page in Bootstrap3.

The page has 6 thumbnails.

- For desktops, I want to display 3 thumbnails per row (in 2 rows);
- For tablets, 2 thumbnails per row (in 3 rows);
- For mobiles, just one thumbnail per row (in 6 rows, stacked vertically).

Is there a simple set of classes in Bootstrap3 to accomplish this. I don't want to hide/show different blocks for different devices. I want this to be truly responsive, and want the columns to collapse from 3 columns to 2 columns to a single column, as the browser `width` reduces.

Is this possible?

Comment: `col-md-4`, `col-sm-6`, `col-xs-12`.

Comment: Thanks everyone, for your suggestions. I just implemented your suggestions on my page - http://hurtigruten.in/r-index.php Can you view it properly on your mobile / tablets? Your feedback would be much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use:

- `col-md-4`, for 3thumbs per page in desktop device
- `col-sm-6` ,for 2thumbs per page in small devices
- `col-xs-12`, for stacked thumbs in extra small devices

Take a look at bootstrap [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

---

```css
.row div:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
  background: red;
  height: 100px
}
.row div:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 100px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it would be right to add a block `<div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>` between the third and fourth cells.

Comment: if you test it you will see that won't be needed

Comment: I see. It's because you use `height: 100px`. But why have you added `<div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>` ?

Comment: because was in need that, again test it ;)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/e4kh8mz6/  I removed the box and simplified table. What I did not notice?

Comment: @GlebKemarsky thanks, was most likely in one of my edits where I needed, now I don't . ;)

Comment: Perhaps you want to achieve something like that https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/s5umrdcg/ I've replace first `height: 100px;` by `height: 150px;`

Comment: Ya would be an Idea yes. But for the moment I made simpler for the OP

Comment: How interesting it turns out. But I think it would be correct to correct something in the code :)

Comment: You need to change CSS too. All divs have to get `height: 100px`.

Comment: My divs are all with the same height

Comment: The first and the second - yes, but not the third.

Comment: If every div has color and each div with chilly has height how come there is no div without height?

Comment: Check your answer: `.row div:nth-of-type(3n+1) { height: 100px
} .row div:nth-of-type(3n+2) { height: 100px }`. So `.row div:nth-of-type(3n)` has default `height: auto`. Try to run your code snippet.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky you were right, it was having the same `height` till I removed the `clearfix` div, now that I removed it I fixed the CSS. (I was replying from the phone btw)

Comment: @GlebKemarsky thanks for the suggestion. I added clearfix and it solved the issue. Without that, it was displaying just one thumbnail in the second row, on desktops.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Grid options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options): `col-xs-12` takes a whole row on mobiles; `col-sm-6` takes a half of the row on tablets; `col-md-4` takes one third of the row on the desktops.
2. If thumbnails have different height, the second row can catch on one of them and start earlier than necessary. To avoid this, [we add a class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-clearfix) `clearfix` before starting a new row.
3. We need two rows on tablet and three rows on desktop. Therefore, we have to use different blocks with class `clearfix` on screens with  different width. Classes `visible-sm-block`, `visible-md-block` and `visible-lg-block` are [toggling content across viewport breakpoints](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities).
4. The image with class `img-responsive` [scales nicely to the parent element](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities).

```css
.thumbnails img {
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row thumbnails">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x400/c69/" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/320x380/9c6/" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/340x360/69c/" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x340/c69/" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/380x320/9c6/" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x300/69c/" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```